# using powershell and pipeing output od Select-Object to access selected columns

Tags: powershell, pipe

I have the power shell below that selectes certain fields

```
dir -Path E:\scripts\br\test  | Get-FileMetaData | Select-Object name, Comments, Path, Rating
```

what i want to do is utilize Name,Comments,Path,Rating in further Pipes $_.name etc dosnt work

Comment: Can you show us what "doesn't work" means?  Nothing you're doing here looks wrong to me.

Comment: this didn’t work
dir -Path E:\scripts\br\test\*.docx  | Get-FileMetaData | Select-Object name, FullName, title | Rename-Item $a $a.Replace($_.name,$_.title + “-“ + $_.name)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do something with the output of `Select-Object`, but you want to do it in a pipeline.

To do this, you need to pass the output down the pipeline into a Cmdlet that accepts pipeline input (such as `ForEach-Object`). If the next operation in the pipeline does not accept pipeline input, you will have to set the output to a variable and access the information through the variable,

**Using ForEach-Object**
In this method, you will be processing each object individually. This will be similar to the first option in Method 1 (that is, dealing with individual items in the collection of items returned by `Select-Object`).

```
dir | Get-FileMetaData | Select-Object Name,Comments,Path,Rating | ForEach-Object {
  # Do stuff with $_
  # Note that $_ is a single item in the collection returned by Select-Object
}
```

The variable method is included in case your next Cmdlet does not accept pipeline input.

**Using Variable**
In this method, you will treat `$tempVariable` as an array and you can operate on each item. If need be, you can actually access each column individually, getting everything at once.

```
$tempVariable = dir | Get-FileMetaData | Select-Object Name,Comments,Path,Rating
# Do stuff with each Name by using $tempVariable[i].Name, etc.
# Or do stuff with all Names by using $tempVariable.Name, etc.
```

Comment: I know what you mean but _You cannot directly pass output of Select-Object_ is wrong. There are plenty of cmdlets that bind from the pipeline and you can use `$_` in a scriptblock for instance

Comment: @Matt Ah, my bad. What I meant to say is that you cannot use `$_` as an input to another cmdlet. I've updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Sorry but again Im not sure what you mean by _`$_` as an input to another cmdlet_ is wrong as well. Of course you can do  `$_ | Get-ChildItem` again inside a loop or scriptblock.... I don't mean to pick but I want to be sure you are not misleading the op. You don't typically would be a better statement

Comment: `Get-ChildItem | New-Item -Path ~\Different\Directory -Type File -Name {$_.Name}` would work

Comment: @Matt Thanks for pointing these stuff out. I think my confusion was about the `$_` variable itself. Will it be correct for me to say that "`$_` is a variable that is equivalent to the output of the current pipeline, and can be used in pipeline only if the next Cmdlet accepts Pipeline Input"?

Comment: Would be better just to quote https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. _Contains the current object in the pipeline object.
       You can use this variable in commands that perform an action on every
       object or on selected objects in a pipeline._ Only because the cmdlet does not need to accept pipeline input and you can still use $_ in its parameters.